# Sony Ericsson registers two devices when connected to USB port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, linux-device-driver

I am very curios that why does every Sony Ericsson phone (w200i,2660 etc) register two ttyACM devices when connected to PC via USB? This also introduces complications in interfacing with the mobile. **Can any one explain this please?**

---

Me and my Colleague are writing an SMS gateway using Python-Gammu, and we are having a hard time making an automated system which will listen on Udev and provide Plug and Play/Hotplug functionality.

Below is a snapshot of "dmesg" after plugging in the mobile:

```
[ 3335.853330] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 3335.853388] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3373.115701] usb 1-1.4: new full speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[ 3373.245499] cdc_acm 1-1.4:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 3373.246619] cdc_acm 1-1.4:1.3: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[ 3373.247459] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[ 3373.247464] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[ 3373.247519] cdc_wdm 1-1.4:1.7: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[ 3373.247565] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two devices because your phone exposes two USB interfaces. As you can see in your log there are two kernel modules loaded for your phone.

```
[ 3373.247464] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN     
[ 3373.247519] cdc_wdm 1-1.4:1.7: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
```

From the Kconfig of the `cdc-wdm` module:

```
This driver supports the WMC Device Management functionality
of cell phones compliant to the CDC WMC specification. You can use
AT commands over this device.
```

So you end up with two "modem" devices(acm, wdm) since both can use the [AT-Command Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_command) to communicate.
I don't know anything about the WDM specifications, but i hope i could help you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :) The problem is one is faulty and doesn't work with sending and receiving SMS through AT command set. The other one is good, I will read up a bit, your answer is already pretty concise.